# Compare now() and return the closest previous date and the closest next date SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I execute an sql query that returns two values only, comparing a date type before now() and one after now().

I have created an sql query for one solution, but how can I combine the below sql query to return previous and after now()

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE ordersDate > now()
AND ordersDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ordersDate ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Another sql query that I am trying:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Orders  
 WHERE
 (SELECT min(ordersDate) FROM Orders 
 Where ordersDate > now()) 
 AND
 (SELECT max(ordersDate) FROM Orders 
 Where ordersDate < now());
```

This sql returns more than two values which is not what I want, I just one the before and after now(), two value only.

Expected output given now() value of todays: (I dont know how to create a table here)

```
OrdersID    ordersDate               OrderMade
    4             19/09/2018            yes
    7             21/09/2018            PreOrder
```

Comment: could you please add sample data and your expected output instead of someone, something - it's very tough to answer based on assumption

Comment: @fa06 i have added a bit of examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to have two separate SELECT queries. One query fetching the order before the current datetime, and another query fetching after the current datetime. We can use [Order By Limit](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp) clause, to fetch only one row per Select statement. Then, you can use [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html), to get a combined result.

Try the following query:

```
(
 SELECT *
 FROM Orders
 WHERE ordersDate > NOW() 
 ORDER BY ordersDate ASC LIMIT 1
) 
UNION ALL 
(
 SELECT *
 FROM Orders
 WHERE ordersDate < NOW() 
 ORDER BY ordersDate DESC LIMIT 1
)
```